How can I feed my R code from sjPlot to ggplot2 for more customization?
I am trying to plot the results of a random coefficient growth model I ran with nlme in R. sjPlot is great for plotting the results, but not so great for customization. Accordingly, I would like to feed the results of my sjPlot to ggplot2. I have managed to get something that is acceptable, but ideally I would like to be able to customize the line type, line color, and line size in both the plot and the legend. In addition, the line types (solid, dashed, and dotted) look to be overlayed on top of a solid line. Is there a better way to do this?
While I am unable to share the actual data, imagine it looks something like this:
dat <- data.frame(
  Event = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4),
  Linear = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3),
  Covariate1 = c(-1.0, -0.5, 0.0, 1.0, -0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.5, -2.0, 1.0, -2.0, -1.0, 1.0, 2.0),
  Covariate2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, -2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1),
  X1 = c(2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, -2, -2, 0, 1, 2, -2, 0),
  X2 = c(-2, -2, -2, -2, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1),
  X3 = c(2, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -2, -1, 0, 1, -2),
  X4 = c(2, -2, -1, 1, -2, -2, -1, 2, 0, -1, 2, 0, 1, -2, 1, 1),
  Outcome = c(0.01, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40, -0.20, -0.20, -0.30, -0.40, -0.10, 0.00, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40, 0.60, 0.80, 0.90)
)

The growth model looks something like the following:
library(nlme)
mod <- lme(Outcome ~ 1 + Covariate1 + Covariate2 +
               Linear + I(Linear^2) +
               X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 +
               (Linear * X1) + (Linear * X2) + (Linear * X3) + (Linear * X4),
            random=~1|Event,
            correlation=corAR1(form=~1|Event),
            data=dat,method="ML",
            control=lmeControl(opt="optim"))
summary(mod)

I then ran my sjPlot:
plot <- sjPlot::plot_model(mod,type="pred",
                   terms=c("Linear [all]","X1"),
                   axis.title=c("Time","Outcome"),
                   title="Time by X1",
                   ci.lvl=NA,
                   legend.title="")

I then fed the sjPlot to ggplot2 as follows:
plot +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = group, color = group), size = 1.5) +  
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "grey", "brown"),  
                     labels = c("Low X1", "Average X1", "High X1")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dashed", "dotted")) +  
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c("solid", "dashed", "dotted"))),
         linetype = FALSE) +  
  theme(
    legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA, color = NA)
  )

The result looks like this:

I am curious if what I've tried is the best/cleanest way to plot my model and if there is a way to remove what looks like a solid line going through my line types. It feels very clunky.

This is a good question, but we definitely need a [mcve]. Can you make up an example with a built-in data set, if sharing your data is too difficult?

Hi @BenBolker. Thanks for the response. You've helped me plenty of times before via other mediums (e.g., multilevel listserv). I appreciate you stepping up here. Is the addition I provided what you were looking for?

looks good at a glance (haven't tried it)

After correcting the typo, I get object 'Linear' not found

My apologies, @Edward. I've corrected the variable name.

The sample data you've got here won't allow us to fit a model because the system is computationally singular.  Can you make up a bigger example where lme() will actually succeed?
